# Android: Parse JSON from url with HttpUrlConnection instead of HttpClient

Tags: android, json, parsing, url

I'm trying to parse a JSON from an url and already found some solutions that worked, but only with HttpClient - and since that isn't supported anymore I want (and need) to do it with HttpUrlConnection but I can't get it to work with that.

My JSON data looks like this

```
[
    {
        "Id":12345,
        "Abc":
            {
                "Name":"Testname"
            },
        "Start":"2015-08-28T10:07:00",
        "End":"2015-08-28T10:08:00",
    },
    {
        "Id":23456,
        "Abc":
            {
                "Name":"Testname2"
            },
        "Start":"2015-08-28T10:07:00",
        "End":"2015-08-28T10:08:00",
    }
]
```

What's the simplest way to parse the JSON data into a JSON Object? (I want to show the data in a ListView later)

Comment: The fact it is JSON should be irrelevant. The problem it seems you are having, is understanding how to use HttpUrlConnection. Vogella has a [wonderful tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNetworking/article.html#javanetwork_overview) on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185338/java-httpurlconnection-returns-json
You can use a JSON Library (Jackson, Gson, ...) to get objects from the json. This is no big deal and has nothing to do with HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: Also consider looking at using Gson to parse Json into usable objects :)

Comment: show us what you tried so far. and if you are getting this response means there is no problem with httpUrlConnection.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public String getJSON(String url, int timeout) {
    HttpURLConnection c = null;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        c.connect();
        int status = c.getResponseCode();

        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();
                return sb.toString();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
       if (c != null) {
          try {
              c.disconnect();
          } catch (Exception ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then parse the `JSON` with some JSON library like for example [`GSON`](https://github.com/google/gson) doing something like this:

```
JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(getJSON(url, timeout));
JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON data is like you say, the parser can fail to parse it, because it's not a valid JSON.

```
"End":"2015-08-28T10:08:00",
```

Removing the coma on the last field of an object can help you.

**Edit (response to Andreu Rodríguez i Donaire comment):** org.json native library provided by Android can also do the job.