# How to parse a link?

Tags: java, android

How to parse a link only if a value came from the search and it is not empty?
The problem is that even a link without a value at the end gives the result https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser?app_id=e5bc806d&app_key=5f7521ffeefe491b936cea6271e13d3d&ingr=

And I need to display values ​​only if a value comes from the searchView at the end, how to organize it correctly? I've tried it this way and it still doesn't work!

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    String current = "";

    try {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        SEARCH_TEXT = binding.searchs.getQuery().toString();

        try {

            url = new URL(PARSE_URL + END_URL + SEARCH_TEXT);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

            int data = isr.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                current += (char) data;
                data = isr.read();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return current;
}
```

Comment: The data seems to be valid JSON data, why don't you parse it to an JSON object using the built-in JSON library or a third party one so accessing the fields is getting more easier?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14185338/150978

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say you want to process the URL only if there's a value in the ***ingr*** query? If so:

```
fun shouldCallAPI(uriString: String) =
    Uri
        .parse(uriString)
        .getQueryParameter("ingr")
        .isNullOrEmpty()
        .not()
```